# SQL order elements by other table field but in a certain order

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have 2 tables:

- **table `object`:**

  - `ID`
  - `title`
- **table `category`:**

  - `ID`
  - `title`
  - `object_id`

I want to set a query to get objects order by category in custom order, for example, first objects where category ID is 214, second 219, etc.

And I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  object.* 
FROM object
INNER JOIN category
  ON category.object_id = object.ID 
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY object.ID 
ORDER BY
  CASE category.ID 
    WHEN 214 THEN 1 
    WHEN 219 THEN 2 
    WHEN 220 THEN 3 
    WHEN 216 THEN 4 
    WHEN 222 THEN 5 
    WHEN 223 THEN 6 
    WHEN 225 THEN 7 
    WHEN 218 THEN 8 
    WHEN 326 THEN 9 
    WHEN 224 THEN 10 
    WHEN 221 THEN 11 
    WHEN 215 THEN 12 
    WHEN 229 THEN 13 
    WHEN 228 THEN 14 
    WHEN 217 THEN 15 
    WHEN 188 THEN 16 
    WHEN 230 THEN 17 
    WHEN 327 THEN 18 
  END ASC
  , object.title ASC
LIMIT 0, 23
```

But it doesn't work, it return object ordered by `object.title` but not by `category.ID`.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is the purpose of the `GROUP BY` clause in this query?

Comment: You probably have `only_full_group_by` disabled and you're not including all columns in the GROUP BY. This will give you unexpected results.

Comment: Maybe see FIELD

Comment: Apparently one object could be put in multiple categories. You are (incorrectly) grouping by object id which gives you one object and a random category from the list of categories it belongs to. `ORDER BY CASE MIN(category.ID)` might work but the result might not be what you expect.

Comment: @GMB `GROUP BY` is so that it does not return duplicate values

Comment: A good rule-of-thumb is NEVER use a GROUP BY clause in a query absent of any aggregating functions. If you want DISTINCT results, use the DISTINCT modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Change your order by to

```
ORDER BY FIELD(category.ID,214,219,220,216,222,223,225,218,326,224,221,215,229,
  228,217,188,230,327),object.title ASC
```

To achieve your goal

Answer (score -1):

You can add a field in the category table with name `order_number` and set the order there. And then simply order by `order_number`. This will also reduce your query and will optimize it.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
  object.*
FROM object
INNER JOIN category
  ON category.object_id = object.ID
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY object.ID
ORDER BY category.order_number
  , object.title ASC
LIMIT 0, 23
```